# Secondary IP addresses and VPN

Tags: networking, google-cloud-platform, google-compute-engine

Our initial need is to deploy multiple web docker containers on a google compute engine instance.
To achieve this and avoid using other ports than 80, we decided to set up multiple internal IP addresses on our instance, this was possible using this : https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/networking#set_a_static_target_ip_address

So now, i'm able to ping my secondary IP addresses located on our docker host from other GCE instances. We set up a specific static route, for which gateway is our instance.

However we did not succeed to set up VPN to reach those IP addresses, indeed, we need to specify a new network in VPN topology but it is forbidden to set up a static route to instance (mandatory to set up secondary IP address) inside a network of the platform. Looks like we are stuck now ..

Thanks for help.

Answer (score 1):

You can use google cloud VPN, you have to set the secondary addresses in the local traffic selectors, and it should work.
See  https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/reference/latest/vpnTunnels And https://cloud.google.com/compute/docs/vpn/creating-vpns